# Default GCC Architecture

Tags: gcc, build, compilation, default

When the `-arch` option is not explicitly specified, which architecture will GCC compile for?  Can I rely on it being the machine's native architecture?

Comment: retagged to change 'architecture' to 'compilation'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, GCC will, by default, compile to the native architecture. At least this is the 'default' behavior.

So, if you're using a default install (either as part of your distro or via its package manager) you can be pretty sure GCC will "do the right thing."

Comment: Actually it depends on the way gcc was configured. By default it will compile for some ancient generic machine like the first x64 cpus in the case of 64 bits.